# Angular JS Coding Standards and guidelines

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular JS development and I would like to know if there are any existing coding standards and guidlines for developing large scale projects using angular JS. The standards should include naming conventions, best practices, performance considerations and project structure etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

John Papa's Angular JS guidelines are very comprehensive and widely used. It is available [here](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide).

(That said, a simple Google search would suffice to answer this question :))